# Script to extract a part of string

Tags: shell

```
ns/APAC_BankTransfers_Publish/CMB/services/svcPublishBankTransfers/flow.xml
```

In the above line and similar lines like this I want to extract whatever is present in  between `services` and `flow.xml` and save it to a variable DIST.

The output should be `svcPublishBankTransfers`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using parameter expansion mechanisms available in POSIX sh:

```
s=ns/APAC_BankTransfers_Publish/CMB/services/svcPublishBankTransfers/flow.xml
s=${s%/flow.xml}    # remove "/flow.xml"
s=${s##*/services/} # remove everything before "services"
echo "$s"
```

This has the advantages of being purely in-process (so faster than approaches that require piping through an external tool), and compatible with all POSIX shells (ash, dash, ksh, etc).

References:

- [BashFAQ #100 ("How do I do string manipulation in bash?")](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100)
- [BashFAQ #73 ("How can I use parameter expansion? How can I get substrings?")](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)

Answer (score 1):

Using BASH regex:

```
s='ns/APAC_BankTransfers_Publish/CMB/services/svcPublishBankTransfers/flow.xml'
[[ "$s" =~ /([^/]+)/[^/]*$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
svcPublishBankTransfers
```

OR else:

```
[[ "$s" =~ /services/([^/]+)/flow\.xml ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
svcPublishBankTransfers
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bash$ echo "ns/APAC_BankTransfers_Publish/CMB/services/svcPublishBankTransfers/flow.xml" | cut -d '/' -f 5
svcPublishBankTransfers
bash$
```